# Selenium with geckodriver - unable to find a matching set of capabilities. What can I do to correct this?

Tags: python, selenium, anaconda, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to get Selenium 3.14 set up with FirefoxPortable in Anaconda on my work computer. Geckodriver was installed via Conda. I have tried current FFP, ESR edition, and developer edition. In all cases, Firefox starts to boot up, but then the console reads "Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities." I tried playing around with the desired capabilities, but that didn't seem to help.

```
import selenium
import pyautogui

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

binary = 'C:/Users/703408793/AppData/Local/FirefoxPortable/FirefoxPortable.exe'

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
driver.get('http://www.python.org')
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys('pycon')
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

https://pastebin.com/3rxsxNqh

Comment: usually means that your firefox and geckodriver do not match..

Comment: Since I am using geckodriver 0.22, what version of Firefox Portable should I try?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, update Firefox and Selenium, after that you need to re-install geckodriver again. This is known issue about not matching versions, if this will not solve your problem you can check it on from their developers platforms, they also offer couple of different solutions.

Comment: I tried all that. Unfortunately I didn't get Firefox to work, however, I was able to get Chrome to work.

Comment: Did you tried to install gecko's 64-bit version manually? (If your system is 64-bit)
Also please delete one of  "  '  " on your binary path. 
binary = 'C:/Users/703408793/AppData/Local/FirefoxPortable/FirefoxPortable.exe'